# find string in all elements of list in R

Tags: r, list

I have the following R list:

```
    mtc<-mtcars

    colnames(mtc)<-c() #my list elements have no column names

    oo<-list(mtc,mtc,mtc)
```

I´d like to look for a pattern in all list elements, let´s say "Mazda", using R base features (no specific packages). The result I´d like to get is another list containing all matching lines accross all elements within the list, i.e

```
    [[1]]
    Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
    Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

    [[2]]
    Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
    Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

    [[3]]
    Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
    Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

Is there an elegant way to to it in R without looping through all list elements?

Any ideas would be very welcome.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep`/`grepl` with `lapply` :

```
lapply(oo, function(x) x[grepl('Mazda', rownames(x)), ])

#[[1]]
#                                                    
#Mazda RX4     21 6 160 110 3.9 2.620 16.46 0 1 4 4 0
#Mazda RX4 Wag 21 6 160 110 3.9 2.875 17.02 0 1 4 4 0

#[[2]]
#                                                    
#Mazda RX4     21 6 160 110 3.9 2.620 16.46 0 1 4 4 0
#Mazda RX4 Wag 21 6 160 110 3.9 2.875 17.02 0 1 4 4 0

#[[3]]
#                                                    
#Mazda RX4     21 6 160 110 3.9 2.620 16.46 0 1 4 4 0
#Mazda RX4 Wag 21 6 160 110 3.9 2.875 17.02 0 1 4 4 0
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use `grep`

```
lapply(oo, function(x) x[grep('Mazda', rownames(x)), ])
```

Comment: Thx @akrun! Your answer goes in the same direction as Ronak's. Both apply to achieve what I'd like.